# PsExec cmd return error when run it through Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, psexec

When I am trying to run PSEXEC it works perfectly when typed manually at powershell

but when run the command through Visual Studio's terminal it display the following error

> psexec : The term 'psexec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

**Note that**
When parsing this cmd in automation code in VS, the remote exe file will not be opened

Comment: "Installation: Just copy PsExec onto your executable path." clearly it's not in your `PATH` environment variable. It's a non-standard utility, you need to make sure Windows can find it.